How can one set a reduced load for a reviewer on OpenReview after they already accepted the reviewer's invitation?
When inviting a reviewer on OpenReview, one may set a reduced load:

How can one set a reduced load for a reviewer on OpenReview after they already accepted the reviewer's invitation?

OpenReview support sent me the following:

The preferred way is to set "Allow Accept With Reduced Load" to Yes when the recruitment invitations are sent. Reviewers can choose their reduced load upon acceptance, otherwise this will default to selecting a reduced load when the user declines. If recruitment invitations were sent with "Allow Accept With Reduced Load" set to No, you'll need to post them manually for reviewers using the python client:  https://docs.openreview.net/how-to-guides/paper-matching-and-assignment/how-to-update-a-reviewers-custom-max-papers

From https://docs.openreview.net/how-to-guides/paper-matching-and-assignment/how-to-update-a-reviewers-custom-max-papers:

To create a reviewers' Custom Max Papers after having run Paper Matching Setup, you can do the following:

If you have not done so, you will need to install and instantiate the openreview-py client.

Create an Edge object with proper params as in the example below:


# For Reviewers
client.post_edge(openreview.api.Edge(
    invitation='<your_venue_id>/Reviewers/-/Custom_Max_Papers',
    head='<your_venue_id>/Reviewers',
    tail='~Profile_ID1',
    signatures=['<your_venue_id>/Program_Chairs'],
    weight=2
))

# For Area Chairs
client.post_edge(openreview.api.Edge(
    invitation='<your_venue_id>/Area_Chairs/-/Custom_Max_Papers',
    head='<your_venue_id>/Area_Chairs',
    tail='~Profile_ID1',
    signatures=['<your_venue_id>/Program_Chairs'],
    weight=2
))

Please make sure the tail value is the profile id of the user. To get the profile id you can use the following call:
profile = openreview.tools.get_profile('role@icml.cc')
profile.id


